# Change "y" labels in a plot

Tags: r, plot, label

I have a plot function defined by:

```
> graphic <- function(x,K=5) 
{ 
  p <- length(x) # items 
  n <- nrow(x) # observations 
  r <- 6 # values
  myf <- function(y) # extract frequencies, no missings
  { 
    y <- y[!is.na(y)] 
    y <- as.factor(y) 
    aux <- summary(y) 
    res <- rep(0, r) 
    res[1:r %in% names(aux)] <- aux 
    100 * res / sum(res) 
  } 
> 
> 
> freqs <- apply(x, 2, FUN = myf) # aplica la funció myf per columnes   
> df2 <- expand.grid(vals = 1:r, item = 1:p) # crea totes les
> combinacions possibles    df2$freq <- as.numeric(freqs) # afegeix les
> freqüències    # gràfic    a <- paste("Items 1 to",ncol(x))    titol
> <- paste("Frequency plot for", as.character(substitute(x))) 
>      plot(df2$item,df2$vals,type="n",xlim=c(1,p),ylim=c(1,r),xaxt = "n", 
>        xlab=bquote(.(a)), ylab="Item values (1 to 6)", ann=FALSE) 
>   
>   
> 
>   axis(1, at = 1:length(x) ,labels=names(x), las=2, cex.axis=0.8)   
> title(bquote(.(titol)), 
>         sub = "For each item, square sizes are proportional to frequences ", 
>         cex.main = 1,font.main= 2, col.main= "black", 
>         cex.sub = 1, font.sub = 1, col.sub = "black") 
>      points(df2$item,df2$vals,pch=22,col="black", bg="gray", cex=(df2$freq/n)*K)  }
```

I cannot upload a image because I'm not allowed for my reputation but: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g1h77z3ob0zf2jj/Rplot.png?dl=0
(when i get mot reputation i'll upload the file)
I want that six to take another value, for example "TT", but i can't find how to do it. Any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look to [this external link](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html), in the section **Axes** at the bottom of the page.

You need to:

1) Delete your y-axis with the option ***yaxt="n"*** in your function `plot(x, y, yaxt="n")`.

2) Add a custom y-axis with `axis(side, at=, labels=, pos=, lty=, col=, las=, tck=, ...)` and precise the option `labels = c("1", "2", "3",..., "TT")` as you wish.

The code below should work for you:

```
## your x-axis is already deleted, so you do the same for y-axis, adding yaxt="n"
plot(df2$item,df2$vals,type="n",xlim=c(1,p),ylim=c(1,r),xaxt = "n", yaxt="n", 
        xlab=bquote(.(a)), ylab="Item values (1 to 6)", ann=FALSE)
## x-axis already created 
axis(1, at = 1:length(x) ,labels=names(x), las=2, cex.axis=0.8) 
## y-axis creation 
axis(2, at = x, labels=c("1","2","3","4","5","TT"), las=2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought i could only use the argument "axis" once and i was getting crazy.